# specify pattern at the beginning of string in regular expression

Tags: regex, pcre

I have some string with multiple possible values:

```
e
(space)Exact
Exact
exact
phase
```

I want to get only the first four values, the regular expression I came up with is:

```
^\s*e
```

it means at the beginning of the string it has 0 or more white space followed by e(or E, case insensitive), howevever it always filters out the case

```
(space)Exact
```

my guess is it take `^` as not instead of beginning of string. How can i correct that? I use Perl Compatible Regular Expressions(PCRE) as the matching engine.

Comment: It does seem to work, see [demo](http://regex101.com/r/kA1iY7)

Comment: turned out this one works for me: ^\\s*e . i ran it from mongodb commandline.

Answer (score 1):

Try the using the mode modifiers in your regex to turn on ^$ match at linebreaks; and also, if necessary case insensitive

```
(?mi)^\s*e
```

Answer (score 0):

The ^ character means only the beginning of a string. The beginning of a new line does not count as the beginning of a string. So this would not work if more than one are inside the same "string" object. Not sure how pcre works, but if you want to be able to match the begging of a line also you have to have the multi-line flag enabled.

Edit: If you want to pick up the beginnning of a new line go this route instead: `\r\n` at the beginning of the expression and remove the "^"

Edit #2 (because I feel like doing regex): here's what you're looking for:

```
(\b)[eE]+\w*
```

Comment: I just edited this with the code you need to do what you want.